# "Het" ternary and n-ary relations in $\bf Rel$?

Tags: category-theory, relation-algebra

Are n-ary relations, with n > 2, in $\bf Rel$ - the category of sets as objects and relations as arrows?

By "het" (heterogeneous) relations I mean relations between distinct sets, so $X \to Y$, as opposed to "hom" (homogeneous) relations $X \to X$.

Any relation, regardless of arity, can be expressed as a subset of product of sets, so a het ternary relation is a subset $\rho \subset X \times Y \times Z$.

Are such relations in $\bf Rel$? As a starting point, $\bf Set$ has products but how is $\rho$ represented as an arrow? If $\rho : X \times Y \to Z$ why is $X \times Y$ in $dom$ and $Z$ in $cod$?

Certainly any permutation should represent the same $\rho$ but then how is the equality between the permutations encoded in $\bf Rel$?

Answer (score 3):

The arrows of $\mathbf{Rel}$ are only binary relations. So no, there aren't any ternary relations in $\mathbf{Rel}$.

(of course, $\mathbf{Rel}$ *does* have binary relations from $X \times Y$ to $Z$)

"Hom", incidentally, is a very poor choice of notation here, given that the trigraph already has a meaning (and refers to a rather fundamental notion of category theory).

Comment: Ok good poing about hom vs. het but what's a better pair of terms, endo vs. exo? that's not so known. - But, your comment seems inconsistent with Qiaochu's above, what am I missing?

Comment: @alan: "Literal meaning" versus "what you can construct with it". To push Qiaochu's meaning, note that $\mathbf{FinVect}$ has *only* linear maps as arrows, nothing else. But despite this limitation, we can still exploit the tensor product in order to do multilinear algebra in $\mathbf{FinVect}$.

Comment: Right. Strictly speaking, the tensor product on $\text{FinVect}$ and on $\text{Rel}$ are extra data, so one needs to talk about them as monoidal categories rather than as categories to access that data.

Answer (score 3):

$\text{Rel}$ encodes relations in various ways; for example, a relation $X \to Y$ can be encoded equivalently as

- a morphism $X \to Y$,
- a morphism $X \times Y \to 1$, or
- a morphism $1 \to X \times Y$.

Here $X \times Y$ refers to the set-theoretic product, which is *not* the categorical product in $\text{Rel}$; it is just a [monoidal product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoidal_category) turning $\text{Rel}$ into a [closed monoidal category](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_monoidal_category). Using this monoidal product, you can encode $n$-ary relations, again in various ways. For example, a ternary relation among sets $X, Y, Z$ can be encoded equivalently as

- a morphism $X \times Y \to Z$,
- a morphism $Y \to X \times Z$,
- a morphism $1 \to X \times Y \times Z$,

and so forth. This is closely analogous to how a linear transformation between finite-dimensional vector spaces $U \to V$ can be encoded equivalently as

- a morphism $U \to V$,
- a morphism $1 \to U^{\ast} \otimes V$,
- a morphism $U \otimes V^{\ast} \to 1$.

The precise structural similarity is that $\text{Rel}$ and $\text{FinVect}$ are both [dagger compact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dagger_compact_category), but $\text{Rel}$ has the additional distinction that every object is self-dual.

Comment: A more intuitive way of saying this is that morphisms in $\text{Rel}$, as a monoidal category, shouldn't be thought of as having a directionality. They merely involve some unordered collection of objects.

Comment: +1 for the explanation - I've not seen this before in category books. But before I accept, if binary relation is specialized to function, I don't see how $X \times Y \to 1$ is the same as $1 \to X \times Y$. For example if the latter is an injection, it's a *part* of $X \times Y$, then the interpretation of the surjective dual is *partition* of that product set. Are these the *same* relation?

Comment: @alan: the whole point of working in $\text{Rel}$ is not to restrict to functions. There is a natural identification between relations $X \times Y \to 1$ and relations $1 \to X \times Y$, but this identification doesn't respect the subset of functions.

Comment: I understand "not to restrict to functions" - nevertheless functions are special relations, so what holds for relations must hold for functions... (By the way, a part from 1 is a point and a partition to 1 is also a trivial partition - I didn't state that explicitly above).

Comment: @alan: no. I am not claiming that some property holds for all relations. I am claiming that some property holds for all homsets of a particular kind in the category of relations. The first claim is that there is a natural identification between the sets $\text{Hom}_{\text{Rel}}(1, X \times Y)$ and $\text{Hom}_{\text{Rel}}(X, Y)$. The second claim is that this identification cannot respect the subset of functions. Which of these claims do you either not understand or disagree with?

Comment: Regarding the first claim, I take it a natural map relates the hom-sets you mention as well as $Hom_{Rel}(X \times Y,1)$. Re 2nd claim, does "respect" mean the same as preserve? To illustrate, can you provide a counterexample, say with X, Y, Z small finite sets?

Comment: @alan: yes. Take $|X| = 2, |Y| = 3$. Then there are $6$ functions $1 \to X \times Y$ but $9$ functions $X \to Y$. (But there are $64$ relations $1 \to X \times Y$ and also $64$ relations $X \to Y$.)